# Can we use artificial intelligence in law?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, thought

I'm from india, there are more than 3 crore cases pending in different courts of India
which is nearly impossible to solve in a limited period of time.. unless we use robot instead of a person.
I know it doesn't make any sense but is that possible to create an artificial intelligence that can consider all the aspects of law and give justice to all cases as a human?

Comment: This is already being done in the USA for several years: https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2018/11/algorithms-court-criminals-jail-time-fair/

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - excellent answer - I would go for it. I think you don't even have to lengthen it any further, as the question is whether we can use it (opposed to *how*). I think it's borderline ontopic, but folks around here may know a lot more about AI than, *e.g.* folks over at law.se